# Getting the Session Inside an ASP.Net ScriptMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have a list of objects which I store in the session.  This list then appears on a web page with little "X"s next to each item.  When one of them is clicked I use Javascript to remove the item from the list on the page and then I send an AJAX call to the server to remove the item from the list in the session also.  Here's where things get a little tricky.  I'm using a ScriptMethod that looks like this (C#):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod, System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public static void removeListItem(string itemNumber)
```

The problem is that this is a **static** method which means I don't have access to the Page variable which in turn means I don't have access to the Session.  Now the sessionID is sent with the request (which I also can't access) and the server has the session so I would assume that there's some way to take that ID and access the session.  Is there a way to access the session from a static method like this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use  `HttpContext.Current.Session` instead of direct call to `Session`

more info in this [article](http://www.apijunkie.com/APIJunkie/blog/post/2008/01/How-to-access-an-ASPNET-Session-object-inside-a-static-function-%28error-CS0120%29.aspx)

Comment: I knew it'd be something simple like that.  Thanks!